# Pycharm: "No Python interpreter configured for the project" everytime

Tags: python, pycharm

Every time I open PyCharm I get this message:

> No Python interpreter configured for the project.

So I set the interpreter, everything works fine, then I close PyCharm and reopen it, and the message pops up again.

Reinstalling Python and Pycharm didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Are you opening individual files?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#local-interpreter

Comment: I am opening individual files, yes.
I tried the jetbrains link without any luck

Answer (score 4):

One way you could try is: Run --> Edit Configurations --> set your interpreter there. That "sticks" for me...

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening individual files then try setting the default settings.

File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter.

I think when you are opening individual files you are not loading the project. This sets a default interpreter so opening a file without loading the project should give it this interpreter.

If this doesn't work then open pycharm normally and select the project that you are working on.

Comment: Tried this, but when i re-open Pycharm, the default settings are gone.

Comment: I think that's because PyCharm creates a project for that single file in a temporary location. It is probably better to create a project for those files and just open the project every time.

Comment: Created a project, everything works fine. Thank you, my hero.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my solution was the following:

- read the following url: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter
- Instead of using Homebrew (Mac), I downloaded Python directly from https://www.python.org/downloads/
- Installed Python
- Reboot the PyCharm
- The system came with the same message BUT it now included the newly found path to the installed Python. Clicked on it.
- PyCharm now works, well, like a charm